# .NET7 Docker Can't Connect to SQL Server On windows server , Docker Exited (137) but on local windows is work well and use mem less than 100 mb

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core, docker-network

I'd like to ask about .NET7 + Docker.

1. Now I try to connect EF Core (from Docker .NET7) to a SQL Server database (the database is not on Docker) got error.

> An error occurred using the connection to database '__DATABASENAME' on
> server '__IP:__PORT'. An exception occurred while iterating over the
> results of a query for context type '__DBCONTEXTNAME'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could
> not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to
> SQL Server)

Like this, in the local window machine, even though normally the local machine can connect via code .NET/SSMS to SQL Server with the same IP inside Docker AND I already try to Telnet inside Docker to my SQLSERVER IP:1433 and it can't connect to SQL Server, I ever tried creating a network, then put this Docker in the network  both macvlan, bridge  and then I want to add the public IP database SQL Server that I want and put it in the Socker  network. How can I do? I've only ever been able to put other Docker containers to the same network, but in this case the SQL Server database is not in Docker.

2. Exited (137) When I placed it on the Kinux server, when I ran it on local windows there was no problem. Looking at the docker UI, it used less than 100mb of memory. But when I placed it and tried running it, there was a problem. Try inserting -mem I tried not inserting it and it still stuck with Exited(137) as well. How should I fix it?

> docker run -it -d --memory="2g" --memory-swap="2g"
> --memory-reservation="2g"

Comment: If you `docker inspect YourContainerId` and look at the `State` properties in the JSON output does it say `"OOMKilled": true`? I'd be surprised if it did. This sounds more like a firewall issue, or perhaps an incorrect port. What does the connection string look like when it works successfully on your Docker host machine?